# How to type A with Circle in Ubuntu 16.04 With Dead-keys?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, usability, dead-keys

I see no dead-key symbol for circle in Fig. 1 which is about my used keyboard layout, English Dvorak, you can use English Qwerty with dead-keys to test the same thing. 
There is small circle at bottom-left-corner however but I cannot type it.

Fig. 1 My keyboard layout, English Dvorak with dead-keys

[image]

I can type A/O/... with dots but not A/O/... with circle.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+W => å

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+W => Å

Comment: Great! It so easy to miss a single special character in the picture. I have another thread where dynamics would help in usability https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382987/16920 - - I make so many mistakes here Right Alt + W because pressing often CTRL-W in stress by accident. It would really help to get a dynamical viewer. What do you think?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Maybe.. Have never used OS X. In this case the answer was there right before your eyes. ;)

Comment: Yes, but it is not always easy to find when you type many types of keyboards in many environments. Dynamics would help a lot.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Not saying it wouldn't.